# NHibernate Component mapping (Creating Criteria)

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, components, mapping

Is there any way to create an “alias” for a component?
I have a “Criteria Builder” that takes strings in the format of “Address.City” (or “User.Address.City”, …) and creates an ICriteria (filters and sorts) based on it.
I am using components to map the “Address” class so it stays in the same table as “User”.

The exception I am getting is:
NHibernate.QueryExceptioncould not resolve property: City of: MyNamespace.User

If I attempt to do not create an “alias” for the Address Component, it works just fine.
However, as it is a criteria builder, is there a way to detect that “Address” is a component and avoid the call criteria.CreateAlias(“Address”)? Any work around?

[This](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2335410&sid=37a2a95223e929ae6cccfc183af6af28) is the same question as mine, however the solution is not viable to me (I do not create criteria manually for each query).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: @Yads - I actually have no code with me right now. It should be simple as the "User" class referencing the "Address" class through a property. In the mapping for user I have "Address" as a component. Please look at https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2335410&sid=37a2a95223e929ae6cccfc183af6af28 as it is pretty similar to my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't create an Alias for Address because Address is not a mapped entity. The only difference between `CreateAlias` and `CreateCriteria` is that the former returns the original Criteria, whereas the latter returns the new Subcriteria. So the only classes you can create Criteria for are classes that have been mapped. Since components are not mapped classes, you can't create a criteria around them.

The only suggestion I have is to have your Address class either to implement an empty descriptor interface like IComponent or mark it with a custom ComponentAttribute. Then your CriteriaBuilder can check whether or not the class it's creating a criteria for has this meta data and ignore it.

Comment: I think that using reflection to check for an attribute would be too expensive (my starting point is a string "Address.City"). Unless you have something else in mind? How would the "empty descriptor" help in this case? Could you post some code? All I needed was CreateAlias to be smart enough and detect if the class was component, or a method that could tell me that... =/ Thanks for you help!

Comment: @Frederico, I'm not totally sure without seeing your code how your CriteraiBuilder works. Perhaps you can just do a check like `if (objToMap is IComponent) //do not call CreateAlias`